# Reload container view IOS

Tags: ios

I am using a container view in my application. I would like to be able to reload the container view, like if I dismissed the linked UIViewController and reloaded it. Is it possible to do it? Can I at least use codes to alloc it, so that I can delete it and re-add it?

Comment: Isn't that done automatically when pop a viewcontroller that you've pushed before? Or what is that `linking`?

Comment: by linking I mean setting a viewcontroller as viewdidload for the container

Comment: Can you add some code? What's the class of that container?